How do you use AWS Amplify Auth module to do a SAML signin flow
I have created an AWS Cognito User Pool with a SAML provider.
I have a REACT App using Amplify UI and I want the user to signin using the SAML provider. (Note I am not using the hosted ui).
I have looked at the Amplify doc https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/advanced-workflows/ and https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration but doesn't seem to cover the SAML case.
Can someone please point me to some sample code (or documentation) which shows how to do this.

The documentation is up to date now you can check here :
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/concepts/external-identity-providers/#configure-saml-provider
